# D3 chart with search box

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created a chart in D3 where nodes show the time at which particular individuals created a document.  The chart also presents a search box, which turns nodes red depending on whether the search box input matches the words associated to that document (these words are listed in column 5 of the dataset - please see below for dataset).

[image]

My problem: once a search has been input into the box (ie. 'fish'), the website visitor must hit 'refresh' in order to run a new search (ie. 'dog'). I would prefer that instead, the chart remains visible when a new search is initiated, and the 'try it' button merely switches the colours of the nodes to reflect the new search choice. Here's what I have so far:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

g.hidden line,
g.hidden path {
  display: none;
}

path {
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}

circle {
  fill: #FF00FF;
  stroke: navy;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

g.tick text y {
  font-size: 30px;
  font: Garamond;
}

g.tick text x {
  font-size: 10px;
  font: Garamond;
}

g.tick line {
  display: none;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta chartset="utf-8">
  <title>Interactive scatterplot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var txtName = 0;

    function sayHi() {
      var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
      console.log(txtName.value);



      var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

      d3.csv("doc.csv")
        .row(function(d) {
          return {
            creator: d.creator,
            date: parseDate(d.date),
            number: Number(d.number),
            doc: d.doc
          };
        })
        .get(function(error, data) {
          var height = 300;
          var width = 500;

          var minDate = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
          var maxDate = new Date(2011, 1, 1);

          var y = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(['', 'may', 'milly', 'maggie', 'molly', ''])
            .range([300, 225, 150, 75, 15, 0]);

          var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([minDate, maxDate])
            .range([0, width]);

          var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
          var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

          var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");

          margin = {
            top: 40,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 50
          };

          var redBox = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("fill", "orange");

          var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            //.filter(function(d) {return d.doc = "milly";})
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
              return x(d.date);
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
              return y(d.creator);
            })
            .attr("r", 4)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              if (d.doc == txtName.value) {
                return "red"
              } else {
                return "black"
              }
            });
          console.log(txtName.value);

          chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(14));
          chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

        });
    }
  </script>

  <textarea id="txtName" name="txt-Name" placeholder="Search for something.."></textarea>
  <button onclick="sayHi()">Try it</button>

  <!-- <div class="test-wrapper"> -->

  <!-- </div><!-- .test-wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the dataset:

```html
date number creator  doc
6/16/2000 3 molly 3 rat
2/25/2002 4 may 2 cat
12/05/2004 3 molly 4 fish
07/06/2006 1 milly 1 dog
09/07/2003 4 may 4 fish
12/10/2001 4 may 3 rat
6/15/2005 2 maggie 3 rat
06/09/2004 1 milly 4 fish
10/05/2005 1 milly 3 rat
10/07/2003 4 may 1 dog
1/19/2009 4 may 2 cat
10/30/2007 1 milly 4 fish
8/13/2009 4 may 2 cat
9/30/2004 3 molly 1 dog
1/17/2006 4 may 3 rat
12/18/2009 3 molly 1 dog
11/02/2007 2 maggie 3 rat
4/17/2007 1 milly 4 fish
```

Currently, the creation of the graph and the process of obtaining the search-box value fall under one function.  I tried to make them separate, but ending the function before the creation of the graph meant that the graph did not recognize the variable `txtName`.  I also tried copy-pasting the block relating to the colour of the circles to the `sayHi` function, but this makes the graph unresponsive.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're drawing the chart *after* the button is clicked. That's not a good idea for changing the colours of the circles when the user clicks the button.

So, remove that inline function call and the `sayHi` function altogether. Then, inside the `d3.tsv` callback (that's a TSV, not a CSV), get the value of the text area:

```
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var txtName = d3.select("#txtName").node().value;
  circles.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.doc === txtName ? "red" : "black";
  })
})
```

Here, `circles` is your circles' selection. Remember to name your selections.

Here is a demo using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/dhy4yt2z/1/

PS: your code have several other minor issues that should be corrected, like the use of margins.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `circles` to a variable and just change the `fill` based on the `textarea` value.

I've used a bit of `jQuery` so that the user doesn't even have to press the `Try it` button as a bonus. You may remove it if you like.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rrz4s9HRaA6kFgmpufao?p=preview)

Comment: Why mixing D3 and jQuery? You can do that with D3 only: https://plnkr.co/edit/nwrpvgVEiGpMivZUWQFK?p=preview Also, keeping those inlines is not a good idea, the best approach is dealing with the data from inside the callback.

Comment: Aah yes.. I didn't know d3 supports all DOM events. Need to look up a bit on that. Thank you sir @GerardoFurtado!

Comment: Please, don't call me sir! Just remove that jQuery, mixing jQuery and D3 gives me nightmares...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Okay.. I've fixed the plunker now.

Comment: I really like the plunker (especially the way the `change paste keyup` makes the change without pressing the button - so beautiful).  But everytime I try to run it from my text editor, I get asked to download an octet application, which is beyond my skills.  I'm going to try again on the weekend, thank you for your wonderful solution.

Comment: @oymonk Glad I could help. What text editor are you using btw?

Comment: @Aditya - I'm using Atom :-)